# Arduino board : difference between two gnd port

Tags: arduino, led

On `Arduino` board, I see two port gnd : one in power line (a list of port has power label beside), that I call gnd(1). And the one is on the other (the line that has port from 0 --> 13 and gnd), that I call gnd(2).

I don't know the difference between two port, but when I test a LED on breadboard, if one line  I connect to gnd(1), the LED will be lighter than gnd(2) (gnd(2) just has a small red light)

Please explain for me the difference.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you measure the resistance between the two?

Comment: @NicholasAlbion oh, i'm sorry, i don't have enough tools for that.

Comment: Where are you getting your 5V from?  What happens when you connect GND to a good ground source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Arduino Uno]

From reading this page: http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno/ (if this is your board) I can't see that it should be any difference in your gnd ports. Maybe you provide different amount of power? Or do you have too much resistance at one time?

I have used Arduino pretty much and I've never had your issue even if I am using all gnd ports available.

Comment: Does that mean the 2 GND ports are exactly the same and can be used interchangeably?

Comment: Yes I think so anyway. But to know for sure you should raise a question on the arduino forum or read the documentation for your device.

Answer (score 1):

The ground connections are usually directly connected on the board. In my opinion there are at least two good reasons for this design:

1) Ground connections are needed very often. Thus it is convenient to have as many ground connections as possible. Especially if you are experimenting with jumper wires.

2) Ground connections are very important and should be reliable. Thus redundant connections will improve reliability in case of vibrations and or bumps.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience adding an extra GND to my breadboard greatly increases reliability and stability. I have had the same experience of LED turning brighter, but also of digital results becoming unreliable if i'am only using one GND.

I tried fixing my stability issues by adding capacitors to the breadboard, but adding an extra GND was much more effective.